# Query to obtain the lowest price per room per hotel in a relational database

Tags: mysql, relational-database

I have a relational database model based on a hotel booking site set up for a uni project, however I am stumped by one query.

This is as far as I have gotten:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    property.property_id,
    property_name,
    property_description,
    star_rating,
    room_base_price
FROM
    property
INNER JOIN rooms ON property.property_id = rooms.property_id;
```

The problem is that I have several rooms per property listed in my database. In this query, I want to select the room with the minimum price per hotel. The way I am currently doing it, it is showing every single property with every single room and its individual price.

Can anyone advise me on how I can write a query where I will be able to return the lowest price of a room in a property(i.e. a hotel), where it will only be one row per hotel instead of returning multiple rows for each property?

Comment: Please add the schema of both the tables.

Comment: How do you to handle the case where two rooms at the same property both have the same lowest price?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Try following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    property.property_id,
    property_name,
    property_description,
    star_rating,
    room_base_price
FROM
    property
INNER JOIN rooms ON property.property_id = rooms.property_id;
where (rooms.property_id,rooms.room_base_price) in
                                                  (select property_id,min(room_base_price) 
                                                   from rooms
                                                   group by property_id
                                                  )
;
```

Hope it helps!